# Nginx Reverse Proxy to Remote Server

Tags: nginx, proxy, web

Okay, so I know there is a lot of questions about Nginx Reverse Proxy but I don't understand any of the answers. I read the documentation on Nginx's website and I kind of get it but need some help.

So here is what I want.

Visitor ---> Nginx Reverse Proxy ---> Nginx Server (Website)

I know that you can get the reverse proxy to listen to a remote server,  but I can't find the configuration files that I want. I also want to show a static html page when passing through the Nginx Reverse Proxy. So like a page that says "Hosted by this company", like Cloudflare does. I asked someone and they told me if I put the html file on the reverse proxy server then it'll show up when the visitor goes through the server, but I don't understand that concept, how do I get that static html to show up? And what will be the correct configuration be for this? I imagine it'll be different from a normal remote server configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In Nginx reverse proxy configuration it is possible to make some urls to be served from reverse proxy itself without going to source server.

Take a look at the following article: https://www.cevapsepeti.com/how-to-setup-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-wordpress/

In this article you can see in virtual.conf lines 51-55 that error_pages are served directly from reverse proxy, while other assets are fetched from source server first. Cloudflare employs the same concept. I hope this helps.

Comment: Fixed the link now. Sorry